# c# mvc5 Editing a nested collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to edit nested collections and post the values back to the server.
I do not know if this is possible.

Class1 has a collection of Class2

Class2 has Class3

Class3 has a collection of Class4

Class4 has a collection of Class5

I installed package BeginCollectionItem from Nuget.

I created editor templates for each of them. 
But still the editors are not displayed.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveModification","Client", FormMethod.Post, new { @class =     "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Id)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
              @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Classes2"))
              {
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Classes2)
              }                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>    
}

Class2.cshtml
<div class="row">
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Class3)
</div>

Class3.cshtml
<div class="row">             
   @Html.HiddenFor(o=>o.Id)
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-10" >@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Classes4"))
    {              
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Classes4)
    }
    </div>
</div>

Class4.cshtml
<div class="row">                   
     <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-left:30px;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)</div>
</div>
<div class="row">                                    
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Classes5"))
{          
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Classes5)
}          
</div>

Class5.cshtml
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-left:50px;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)</div>
</div>
```

My question: Is this possible using nested editor templates?

update 1:

using fiddler, i see that my response contains my edited values

```
Id
Classes2.index
Classes2.index
Classes2[311410b2-6ce1-4a09-9979-552720f377fc].Id
Classes2[311410b2-6ce1-4a09-9979-552720f377fc].Class3.Id
Classes2[311410b2-6ce1-4a09-9979-552720f377fc].Class3.Quantity
Class3.index
Class3[7e8b7a76-7000-4ec9-8877-d150ffe25dc5].Classes4.index
Class3[7e8b7a76-7000-4ec9-8877-d150ffe25dc5].Classes4[3315b9ce-989d-4229-92c5-a7ba9955539d].Id
Class3[7e8b7a76-7000-4ec9-8877-d150ffe25dc5].Classes4[3315b9ce-989d-4229-92c5-a7ba9955539d].Quantity
Classes4.index
Classes4[d8990f17-9d9d-4f21-81e2-70c012c48922].Classes5.index
Classes4[d8990f17-9d9d-4f21-81e2-70c012c48922].Classes5[a8afe9a0-b6e0-42b7-85aa-f5bd967dcab6].Id
Classes4[d8990f17-9d9d-4f21-81e2-70c012c48922].Classes5[a8afe9a0-b6e0-42b7-85aa-f5bd967dcab6].Quantity
```

But in my controller, the viewmodel does not have the same values, some collections are null. I get only class2 and class3 values.

Answer (score 1):

The `BeginCollectionItem` should be used on a single collection item, not at the collection level. Moreover, if you want to just display the collection without adding and removing dynamically, you should not need it.

In your main view you can simply do this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Classes2)
</div>
```

Call the EditorTemplate `Class2.cshtml`. Razor will automatically cycle over the collection and render your template for each element.

If you want, in the `Class2.cshtml`, you can wrap your code into the:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Classes2"))
{
    // Your Template code here... 
}
```

Comment: I will add other functionalities (add/remove) later on.
For the moment, I am trying to just see how it will work. The hierarchy is being displayed, but my changes are not being sent to my controller. Any idea why?

Comment: Check the input names in the generated HTML. The `name` should map to the model property names, so for example the input field for Class3.Quantity should be named `Classes2[0].Class3.Quantity` where the index (0) will increment for the next item in the collection.

Comment: see my update.. using fiddler I see that the response contains the edited values, but in my controller, the viewmodel contains only part of the edited values. I get Classes2 and Class3. The other collections are null. Any hint?

Comment: The only thing I can see is that the `Classes2.index` is there twice but there is only one element. Also the `Class3.index` should not be there... Anyway, given the complexity of your model, I would try to flatten your collection in a ViewModel so you only have one level of nesting and then in the Controller you can map back and forth between Model and ViewModel.